# Is 'return true' at the end of a method bad practice when exceptions handle all other code paths?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm trying to call a web service that saves user information. Essentially, a 'completion' object is returned with the results of the service call. The code I have can be condensed as follows:

```
public bool SaveUserInformation(ArgsList args) {
    CompletionObject results = SaveService(args);
    if (results.Status == Failed)
        throw SomeException("onoez D:");

    return true;
}
```

Essentially, this method returns a boolean but the value is never false. This seems a little strange to me, so is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you can't change your method to not return anything?  public void SaveUserInformation(...

Comment: Your exception your throwing is not going to return false. Which makes one wonder the point of trying to return the BOOLEAN value of the operation. One would argue the reason your not returning a CompletionObject instead of a bool.  You wouldn't have to even thrown an exception in that case, you could in the main body of code, log the results.

Comment: When "results.Status" is failed, the "SaveUserInformation()" method does not get a chance to return anything - since the Exception code gets executed. If you choose to swallow the exception in the code block that calls SaveUserInformation() method, the return value of SaveUserInformation is the default value of bool datatype (which is false).

Comment: @Greg I'm modelling my service after an existing service in our Framework, which basically follows this exact pattern.. that's the only reason I'd keep it this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not return `void`? If an exception is thrown then you will know it. If it isn't thrown, you know that your function completed successfully (returned true).

```
try
{
   MyFunction();
   //here you know it has successfully completed
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   //...  
}
```

If, however, you're overriding a virtual function which returns bool then you can of course always return true, since you have to return some boolean value anyway. Come to think of it, you can return false as well :)

Comment: Very very design dependent solution, by me. You can not just catch any exception and say: "well, listen, something went wrong out there, so FALSE". No idea what was an exception, no any feedback. Or you need on this level create a cascade of exceptions handling. In general, in my experience, I hate this "silent" exceptions. Very dangerouse, by me.

Comment: @Tigran: I am assuming that `results.Status == Failed` is an exceptional situation. If it isn't then it's a completely different matter

Comment: that is a point, you can never offer this kind of solution extracting it from context. Depends where this code, and what you want it's behaviour looks like. That's why I say "very very design dependent solution".

Comment: @Tigran @Armen I would consider a failed result as an exceptional situation. Would it be constructive to look at it from a more semantic point of view? Currently the calling code would look like this: `if (SaveUserInformation(args)) {...}` which is a little strange. Given this answer, SaveUserInformation(args) seems to make some more sense.

Comment: @raynjamn: if this solution is ok for you, just can use try/catch inside method and leave (if) check during that call. Just like Armen suggests. So the SaveUserInformation(args) in case of any internal exception will return false, otherwise true. Simple.

Comment: @Tigran Yeah I was trying to say that makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Exception` is for exceptional cases.

`Return value` is for indicating caller about something happened inside called function.

*They are completely different design concepts.*

Deside what you want the behaviour of that method looks like.

If there is nothing to notify about, remove return value.

If there is, check if there is really sense to have all that exceptions handling.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this question and after looking at your code, I would say **YES**.

This function returns true regardless of the outcome, so its return value has no meaning.

Now, on the other hand, if you had tried to open a file that did not exist, you would also get an Exception. If you handled that Exception and used a default file or loaded default values and everything still worked out... then returning true would be logical.

The function you have shown is not helpful to anyone using it ...unless you have left something out of it.

Comment: There's a lot taken out of it; I only left in the pieces I felt are relevant to the question.

Comment: I suspected that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why even make it return a boolean? You either return the error as a true/false value or you just return nothing and rely on exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply return `CompletionObject`

```
public CompletionObject SaveUserInformation(ArgsList args) {
    return SaveService(args);
    /*if (results.Status == Failed)
        throw SomeException("onoez D:");

    return true;*/
}
```

I am not able to understand the need for a bool return value as its always true.